# Promoting a GitHub repo and suggestions on new API methods

Tags: github

I have a Session API on GitHub, I have methods such as:

Starting the session, Returning session status, Setting a value within the session array, retrieving a value from the array, specified by a single key, Displaying the array, destroying the session, and a function to make a recursive array search through a multi-dimensional session array to return a value based on the session keys.

What other methods could prove beneficial to this API to make it thrive and work seamlessly within the enterprise/web environment?

Also, what steps are there to promote a GitHub repository to make the API thrive and known within the development community?

Comment: add a link to your github page to your stackoverflow profile ;)

Comment: Provide options for storing session in memcache, redis, apc, database, wincache, etc: there's lots of options people have for session management libraries if they can't write one themselves, so you'd need to provide something useful that the "competition" didn't to make yourself stand out from the crowd